# Android Navigation Drawer custom ListView not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

```
UserFunctions uf=new UserFunctions();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private ContactAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    DatabaseHandler handler=new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());
    Cursor C=handler.getAllContacts();
    if(C!=null)
    {
    while(C.moveToNext())
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String name=C.getString(0);
        String status=C.getString(1);
        String last=C.getString(2);
        String f_gcm=C.getString(3);
        String  image=C.getString(4);



        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length); 

        map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        map.put(KEY_STATUS,status);
        map.put(KEY_PHOTO, decodedByte);
        map.put(KEY_LAST,last);
        map.put(KEY_GCM, f_gcm);
        contactList.add(map);                               
    }
    }
    handler.close();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);


    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(this,
            contactList);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new RecentChatt();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

```
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.DrawerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at com.example.androidhive.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:102)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667):     ... 11 more
02-18 08:12:12.104: I/Process(3667): Sending signal. PID: 3667 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in 102 line. You use don't initializated object

Comment: please post this line

Comment: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 this one and all respective getactionbar are generating exception

Comment: Which activity you extends?

Comment: There is no setter used for the actionbar in your posted code. Check if you forget to set the action bar.

Comment: ow to write a setter for this can you explain

Comment: Maybe, your theme don't supported action bar? (Check your activity in  manifest)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your exception, you got

08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 02-18 08:12:09.773: E/AndroidRuntime(3667): at com.example.androidhive.DrawerActivity.onCreate(DrawerActivity.java:102)

so check line 102 inside your activity to know the reason of null pointer exception.